# Formalised analysis of questionnaires

Tags: categorical-data, references, survey, ordinal-data

I have given a dataset that resembles a questionnaire and I am requested to write a statistics paper on it. I have little to no experience dealing with cross section categorical data.

While I have already performed a logit and a decision tree, it really troubles me that I cannot find any paper with a formalised questionnaire analysis methodology.

Do you have any resource (paper, book) which includes a coherent analysis on categorical and ordinal (likert scale) data to refer to?

Comment: Can you tell us what is your research goals?

Comment: I have given 4 Likert scale Indices; they represent the impact of certain attributes (e.g. Looks, Grades, Money) to become popular. Also, I have been given several demographic data and I want to check which attribute has the highest impact per subgroup (e.g male vs female)